# Incrementing Thread Name

Tags: java, multithreading, increment

I have made a function that takes x amount of parameters. Each parameter, represents a file.

I want every single of these files to be assigned a thread, for counting the words of the files as fast as possible. Currently I have done something that seems to work, however I find myself in trouble of checking the threads as they are all just assigned with the name "t"

It would be nice to somehow increment the name of the threads. The first thread would be t1 and would be assigned to the first file and so on.

```
for (File file : fileList) {
            final File f = file;
            Thread t = null;
            ThreadGroup test = null;
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Scanner fileScan;
                    try {
                        fileScan = new Scanner(f);
                   }
                   catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                       System.out.println("Something went wrong while accessing the file");
                       return;
                    }
                    int words = 0;
                    while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
                        words++;
                        fileScan.next();
                    }
                    System.out.println(f.getName() + ": " + words + " words");
                    System.out.println(Thread.activeCount() + ": ");
                }
            };
            t = new Thread(r);
            t.start();
        }
```

The threadcount goes up as it is supposed when checking with Thread.activeCount(), but I have no clue how to ever contact them as I have assigned all with the name t, which makes it hard to make yet another thread that shall wait for their output.

I hope my explaination clearified the problem :/

Edit:

The idea is that I will count the amount of words in different files, every file needs to be assigned a thread for itself to speed it up. Other than that, I want one thread waiting for the output from all the other threads ( meaning I will have to wait for them to finish, hence why I would appriciate accessing the name of the threads ).

At the end that last thread that has been waiting will use the collected data for it's own actions before closing the program down.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood you well, but can't you just use `new Thread(r, "name")`?

Comment: i think you need to clarify what you are trying to do, you want to access the threads? how exactly? you could create a `List<Thread*>` and right after `t = new Thread(r);` do `myList.append(t);` or you could use a map and map the file name to the thread pointer?

Comment: Gosh this sounds an awful like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) especially the artificial use of a String to hold information better held elsewhere. Why not just use a CountDownLatch or similar construct?

Comment: If using `ExecutorService`, you could also use `ThreadFactory` to manage incremeanting the thread names

Comment: Why not just create a class that implements Runnable, give it an int index or String name field, or whatever information that you want to attach to your threading data, and simply use that?

Comment: The time it takes to count all of the words in a file is going to be some small fraction of a percent greater than the time it takes to _read_ the file from disk.  You can create extra threads to do the counting, but your threads aren't going to do the reading.  The OS is going to read the files, and if the files are all on the same disk, or even if they are on different disks attached to the same bus, then the reading effectively will be single threaded:  The disk can only send one disk block at a time to the host computer.

Comment: "I have assigned all with the name t" -- Time for you to learn about _Java collections_:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/ .  If I was teaching you this ***t, I would not let you even _think_ about messing with Threads before you had mastered collections.

Answer (score 1):

In order to for instance wait for the threads to finish, you need to save references to the threads you create. You could for instance do

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then do `threads.add(t);` at the end of the loop.

After that you could wait for them to finish by doing

```
for (Thread t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

What's problematic however is that there is no way for you to read the result of the threads you've started.

**A much better approach** to this is to use an `ExecutorService` and a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. This way you can submit `Callable<Integer>` instead of `Runnable`, and you'll be able to get the result of the word-count.

Here's an outline to get you started:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
List<Future<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (File f : fileList) {
    results.add(service.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        // ...
    }));
}

for (Future<Integer> result : results) {
    System.out.println("Result: " + result.get());
}
```